# C pointers: void vs other types

Tags: pointers

Why is the following allowed in gcc :

```
void **p1, **p2;

p1=*p2;
```

but this generates an "assignment from incompatible pointer type" error?

```
char **p1, **p2;
p1=*p2;
```

Comment: `char **p1, p2; p1=*p2;` won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `*p2` is of type `void *`, which is *the* generic (data) pointer type. That means, you can assign any data pointer type to a pointer of type `void *`, and you can also assign a `void *` to any type of data pointer. So

```
(some void **) = (some void *);
```

is valid.

However, `char **` and `char *` are pointers to different types and neither of them is `void *`, so you can't assign one to another.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the top part of the code is legal. In both cases, the pointers are of size 4 bytes and point to the first cell of a 4 byte block (on a 32 bit OS).

Comment: Even the arithmetics is different: ((void **) p)+1 should be done by an increment of 4, while ((void *) p)+1 should be an increment of 1. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Ivan 1. Stop making assumptions about `sizef(T *)` (it has nothing to do with the warning anyway). 2. You can do it because `void *` is compatible with ***any data pointer type,*** but `char *` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
char **p1, **p2;
/* Make sure p2 has a valid value (i.e. points to a valid memory location) before the following statement */
p1=p2;
```

The reason it works between `void**` being assigned a `void*` is because void pointers can point to anything.

Comment: the above should also not work since the value of p2 is being converted to a pointer. this should give segmentation fault.

Comment: Why not try running it to see if you get a segmentation fault ? Just these 2 lines will not cause any seg-fault, dereferencing p1 or p2 without assigning a value to it, will cause it. I just posted the code snippet to show how he should be assigning value from p2 to p1. Whether p2 had a valid value in it - that should be taken care of before dereferencing it.

Comment: even if p2 has a valid value it should cause a segmentation fault e.g if say p2 = 'a' and p1=p2. p1 will contain 97 i.e the ascii value of a which is not acceptable and will crash.

Comment: @Koushik - By valid value, I mean a valid memory location. Obviously assigning junk values to a pointer and trying to dereference them is stupid and pointless other than showing what you ought not to do.

Comment: yes a valid memory location satisfies p2. *p2 = &p1 is a acceptable way as you mentioned